# Sizing canvas element in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have a canvas element.  In my React JSX the canvas element is declared like this:

```
                    <div className="circlesBodyRow">
                        <canvas 
                            className="circlesCanvas"
                            height="200px"
                            width="300px"
                            style={{
                                height: "200px",
                                width: "300px",
                            }}
                            onClick={this.handleCanvasClick} 
                        />
                    </div>
```

And everything works the way I expect.  Specifically, in the handleCanvasClick function -

```
    handleCanvasClick(event) {
        const canvas = event.target;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        console.log(event);

        let mouseX = event.clientX - canvasRect.left - canvas.clientLeft;
        let mouseY = event.clientY - canvasRect.top - canvas.clientTop;
        
        //draw a circle centered at the mouse position
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        
        console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
```

A circle appears on my canvas exactly where I click it.  However, I don't want to define the canvas's height and width the way I have in my example.  That is, I don't want to say "200px" I want to say that the canvas is as big as the parent element - "100%" for height and width.

If I replace the "px" measurements in my example with percentage values then the canvas doesn't work right.  One problem is that the canvas is too big - it overflows out of its parent.  A bigger problem is that clicking on the canvas the handleCanvasClick method draws a circle at the wrong point - like there is some offset that is wrong or something.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and/or how to correctly resize my canvas without breaking it?

Answer (score 1):

this can help you, and you can resize it by resizing the `div.circlesBodyRow`

```js
const {useState,useEffect,useRef} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const refCircleBody = useRef(null);
  const [heightWidth, setHeightWidth] = useState([0, 0]);

  const handleCanvasClick = (event) => {
    const canvas = event.target;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    let mouseX = event.clientX - canvasRect.left - canvas.clientLeft;
    let mouseY = event.clientY - canvasRect.top - canvas.clientTop;

    //draw a circle centered at the mouse position
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeightWidth([
      refCircleBody.current.clientHeight,
      refCircleBody.current.clientWidth,
    ]);
  }, [refCircleBody]);

  return (
    <div ref={refCircleBody} className="circlesBodyRow">
      <canvas
        className="circlesCanvas"
        height={heightWidth[0]}
        width={heightWidth[1]}
        onClick={handleCanvasClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.circlesBodyRow {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
.circlesCanvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This works, but it doesn't seem very "react-y" to me that I have to use the query selector.

Comment: i have edited the answer, so i've used `useRef` instead of `query selector`